# Javascript and C# rounding hell

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui

As you know due to genius rounding rule in `C#` we are getting the following values:

```
decimal d = 2.155M;
var r = Math.Round(d, 2); //2.16

decimal d = 2.145M;
var r = Math.Round(d, 2); //2.14
```

Now on client side in `Javascript` I am getting:

```
2.155.toFixed(2)
"2.15"

2.145.toFixed(2)
"2.15"

kendo.toString(2.155, 'n2')
"2.16"

kendo.toString(2.145, 'n2')
"2.15"
```

But I have validations in the backend that is failing due to this. What is the correct way to deal with this kind of situation? How can I sync `C#` and `Javascript` rounding to be sure they both round to the same values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There´s an [overload in C#´s Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms131275(v=vs.110).aspx) accepting an indicator to detmerine how to round when number is half-way between two others. E.g. MidPointToEven rounds the 0.5 to zero as zero is the neartest even number:

```
decimal d = 2.155M;
var r = Math.Round(d, 2, MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero); //2.16

decimal d = 2.145M;
var r = Math.Round(d, 2, MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero); //2.15
```

As per defualt `MidPointToEven` is used your number will allways be rounded to the nearest *even* number. Thuis you get those results:

```
2.155 --> 2.16
2.145 --> 2.14
```

Comment: Missed that one. Thank you! Actually my issue is completely on Javascript side and I will create a new question.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the [midpoint rounding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) rule to be used in C#:

```
decimal d = 2.145M;
var r = Math.Round(d, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //2.15
```

The default value for decimals is `MidpointRounding.ToEven` AKA [banker's rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), it's designed to minimize the bias over multiple rounding operations.

> The round half to even method treats positive and negative values symmetrically, and is therefore free of sign bias. More importantly, for reasonable distributions of y values, **the average value of the rounded numbers is the same as that of the original numbers**. However, this rule will introduce a towards-zero bias when y − 0.5 is even, and a towards-infinity bias for when it is odd. Further, it distorts the distribution by increasing the probability of evens relative to odds.

Comment: Thank you, got it!