# Multiplication gives approximate results

Tags: javascript

Hmm I have an issue with roundings on the client side which is then validated in the backend and the validation is failing due to this issue. Here is the previous question [Javascript and C# rounding hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716347/javascript-and-c-sharp-rounding-hell)

So what I am doing is:

**On client side:**

```
I have 2 numbers: 50 and 2.3659
I multiply them: 50 * 2.3659  //118.29499999999999
Round to 2 decimal places: kendo.toString(50 * 2.3659, 'n2') //118.29
```

**In backend(`C#`):**

```
I am doing the same: 50 and 2.3659
I multiply them: 50 * 2.3659  //118.2950
Round to 2 decimal places: Math.Round(50 * 2.3659, 2) //118.30
```

And validation is failing. Can I do something on the client side?

Comment: You are aware that [floating math "is broken"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), right?

Comment: Right, but the question is what can I do in this case? Do you suggest me to throw away business validations and commit incorrect results?

Comment: Multiply them as integers, not as floats. `50 * 23659` - then move the decimal point as you see fit. Then you'll get same results everywhere. It's not ideal, but it will work.

Comment: Can rounding 2.3659 before multiplication be a solution?

Comment: @Mistalis, no way.

Comment: Maybe send two numbers, result+Number.Epsilon and result-Number.Epsilon, and check for a<=serverside<=b

Comment: Then your best bet is probably a library which defines an actual decimal type or allows you to do mathematical operations on numbers as strings.

Comment: can you suggest the library. Just checked math.js and it is more weird: `math.multiply(50, 2.3659) == 118.295`, `math.round(math.multiply(50, 2.3659), 2) == 118.29`,
`math.round(118.295, 2) ==  118.3`

Comment: You could try bignumber.js (MikeMcl) I guess you can just google the github link. It should give you the correct results. But there are other more-than-capable libraries out there.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this extensively, but the function below should emulate the 'MidPointToEven' rounding:

```js
function roundMidPointToEven(d, f){  
    f = Math.pow(10, f || 0);  // f = decimals, use 0 as default
    let val = d * f, r = Math.round(val); 
    if(r & 1 == 1 && Math.sign(r) * (Math.round(val * 10) % 10) === 5)
     r +=  val > r ? 1 : -1;  //only if the rounded value is odd and the next rounded decimal would be 5: alter the outcome to the nearest even number
    return r / f;
}

for(let d of [50 * 2.3659, 2.155,2.145, -2.155, 2.144444, 2.1, 2.5])
    console.log(d, ' -> ', roundMidPointToEven(d, 2)); //test values correspond with outcome of rounding decimals in C#
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try parseFloat and toFixed functions as follows :

```
   var mulVal = parseFloat(50) * parseFloat(2.3659);
   var ans = mulVal.toFixed(2);
   console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Arithmetic is not always accurate, and such erroneous answers are not unusual. I would suggest that you use `Math.Round()` or `var.toFixed(1)` for this scenario.

Using Math.Round:

```
var value = parseFloat(50) * parseFloat(2.3659);
var rounded = Math.round(value);
console.log(rounded);
```

Prints `118` to the console.

Using toFixed() method:

```
var value = parseFloat(50) * parseFloat(2.3659);
var rounded = value.toFixed(1);
console.log(rounded);
```

Prints `118.3` to the console.

Note that using `toFixed(2)` will give the value as `118.29`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes and I need to round to 2, and you are just lucky that toFixed(1) gave the corect result...